# How to edit Excel file using DataFrame and save it back as Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Mb1ccVDecbg2a-uIoFZtH6BlQQ0ifA-/view?usp=sharing) Excel file. I also put the screenshot of my the file below.
[image: Excel screenshot]

I want to edit the data on `pitch-class` column with this 2 criteria:

1. removing `' '` mark between the text.
2. removing `0` values.
3. removing `[]` mark.

So, for example, from this text:

```
['0', 'E3', 'F3', 'F#3 / Gb3', 'G3', 'G#3 / Ab3', 'A3', 'A#3 / Bb3', 'B3', 'C4', 'C#4 / Db4', 'D4']
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
[E3, F3, F#3 / Gb3, G3, G#3 / Ab3, A3, A#3 / Bb3, B3, C4, C#4 / Db4, D4]
```

Of course, I can do this manually one by one, but unfortunately because I have about 20 similar files that I have to edit, I can't do it manually, so I think I might need help from Python.

My idea to do it on Python is to load the Excel file to a DataFrame, edit the data row by row (maybe using `.remove()` and `.join()` method), and put the edit result back to original Excel file, or maybe generate a new one consisting an edited `pitch-class` data column.

But, I kinda have no idea on how to do code it. So far, what I've tried to do is this:

1. read the Excel files to Python.
2. read `pitch-class` column in that Excel file.
3. load it to a dataframe.
   Below is my current code.

```
import pandas as pd 

file = '014_twinkle_twinkle 300 0.0001 dataframe.xlsx' # file attached above

df = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=None, usecols="C") # read only pitch-class column

# printing data
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(df['pitch-class'].astype(str))
```

My question is how can I edit the `pitch-class` data per row and put the edit result back again to original or a new Excel file? I have difficulties accessing the `df['pitch-class']` data because I can't get the string value. Is there any way in Python to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you do not want to iterate over every row in a pandas dataframe, it is very slow. There are a lot of ways (that you can lean by practice over time) to apply functions over a column/row/the whole dataframe in pandas. In this example:

Convert the column to type string, and replace the ' character with a blank space

```
df = pd.read_excel("014_twinkle_twinkle 300 0.0001 dataframe.xlsx")
df["pitch-class"] = df["pitch-class"].astype(str).str.replace("'0', ", "")
df["pitch-class"] = df["pitch-class"].astype(str).str.replace("'", "")
df.to_excel("results.xlsx")
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. But, the ```0``` still remains in the data. Can I do ```df['pitch-class'].remove(0)``` to omit it?

Comment: @Dionisius Pratama I edited my answer to remove the 0 at the start of the data. If this has answered your question, remember to press the 'Answered' tick :)